# Used nomodeset while installing Ubuntu now not able to go back to Windows

Tags: boot, memory-management

After a lot of struggle I managed to install Ubuntu by adding `nomodeset` in grub but now I have realised Ubuntu isn't really my cup of tea.

Now that I am planning to go back to Windows 10 whenever I try to boot from USB (used MS USB boot software) I end up getting error

`Stop code: MEMORY MANAGEMENT`

[image: http://i68.tinypic.com/6f9k4z.jpg]

I've tried changing boot option from UEFI to Legacy also disabled secure boot, please help

Comment: Can you still get into Linux? What about the Windows recovery console? This sounds very much like a hardware failure.

Comment: Yes I'm able to use Linux not sure about recovery console